# Why does the definite integral of $\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ converge

Tags: integration, complex-integration, trigonometric-integrals

I was taking the integral, $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ and I found out in this process that the answer is equivalent to  $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ where they both equal $\sqrt{\pi/2}$. However I am very confused as to how $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ may converge to an answer when it diverges at the boundary of x = 0.

Comment: the function diverges but the corresponding improper integral converges. Technically the normal Riemann integral does not exist since the function is unbounded but the limit of $\int_a^c dx/\sqrt{x} $ exists as $a\to 0$ for any finite $c>0$.

Comment: This is a standard result proved using complex analysis in Fischer's book for instance. It can be done using contour integration. There are a handful of other proofs.

Comment: Welcome! Note that $\int_0^1\frac{1dx}{\sqrt{x}}$ converges, whereas $\int_0^1\frac{1dx}{x}$ and $\int_0^1\frac{1dx}{x^2}$ both diverge.